# How do I use Graphviz to show a connection?

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz

I have a dataframe with different devices and logins and I am trying to show the connection between the devices and logins. For example, the devices that have the same fingerprint how do I actually code it?

Example of my df

```
      | login  | device | fingerprint | ... |
  0   |   l1   |   d1   |     f1      | ... |
  1   |   l2   |   d1   |     f1      | ... |
  2   |   l3   |   d1   |     f1      | ... |
  3   |   l4   |   d2   |     f1      | ... | 
  4   |   l5   |   d3   |     f3      | ... |
  5   |   l5   |   d1   |     f1      | ... |
```

I want it something like this example graph:

[image: [example of graph]]

and I have been wrecking my brain trying to find a solution but have failed to do so. I am still new to programming. Thanks for the help in advance!

What I have done so far.

```
g.edge('f1', 'd1', label='') 
g.edge('f1', 'd2', label='')

g.node('0', 'l1')
g.node('1', 'l2')
g.node('2', 'l3')
g.node('3', 'l4')
g.node('4', 'l5')
```

[image: 2]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I kind of manually hard coded each device so far....```g.edge('f1', 'd1', label='') ``` and  ```g.node('0', 'l1')``` and so on....

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and where you have problems. It is not clear wht the relation is between the different fields and in the image e.g. the `f3` is not present.